# C# trim datagridview cell string

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

I need to trim a datagridview cell in the textbox2_KeyPress event so that it finds the matching value in the datagrid that's in textbox2 **before** the keypress searches for textbox2's string in the datagrid.

Currently the CellFormatting event occurs after the KeyPress looks for the value.

My code;

```
private void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                iCBOMHDataGridView.DataSource = iCBOMHBindingSource;

                string input = textBox2.Text;
                string output = "";
                textBox2.Text = Regex.Replace(input, @"^\d{4}|[A-z]{2}[0-9]{5},|,|,|\d{|[0-9]{4}/....|\d{1,}\/\d{2,2}\/\d{4}|\s.........|\s|,|,|,|\d*?.$|[*?:/]\n|\r|\r\n", output);

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in iCBOMHDataGridView.Rows)

                    if ((string)row.Cells["PARTNUMBER"].Value == textBox2.Text)

                    {
                        row.Selected = true;
                        MessageBox.Show("Part Number Found");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row.Selected = false;
                        MessageBox.Show("Part Number Not Found");
                    }
            }
        }

       private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex > -1)
            {
               e.Value = e.Value.ToString().Trim();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Despite them being names differently it does still work. The CellFormatting trims all the strings in the DataGrid. However it does it after the KeyPress when I need it to do it after the regex runs but before it located a matching value

Comment: The DataGrid is read only. As it's displaying various sub products that make up a KIT product that the user will scan off with a barcode scanner. They won't be editing the cells. The problem I'm having is that the string in the cells containing the part number that's scanned into textbox2 has whitespace after it so the code doesn't find a match as the textbox2 doesn't have whitespace after it.

Comment: Ah yes I understand now! Apologies, new to this ;)...in that case I still have the issue of no matching value being found in the datagrid despite the fact I can see there is a match..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use KeyDown instead of KeyPress, as that occurs earlier. Not sure if it's early enough though.

Edit: or even the PreviewKeyDown event.

Comment: How would I use a cellformating event in a keydown event? I had thought of the idea but unsure how to implement it effectively

Comment: I've probably completely misunderstood the relationship between the key press and the datagrid then. It sounds like they're actually separate? I probably don't have enough information to suggest a solution. If whitespace is the only problem then why not just trim the strings before comparing them.

Comment: I've corrected the mistake and it's now using one DataGrid. I've moved the regex.replace part to a `textbox2_PreviewKeyDown` event. The trim is in `iCBOMHDataGridView_CellFormatting` and the compare the DataGrid Cells for a matching String from textbox2 is in a `textbox2_KeyPress` event.

Comment: However, it still can't locate the Part Number in the DataGrid. I can confirm that textBox2 does contain the correct Part Number that's shown in the DataGrid.

Comment: Have you looked in the debugger at the actual values you're comparing? Are you certain what the problem actually is? As far as I understand it, the cell formatting in the datagrid happens long before the keypress event, so I'm not sure they're related at all. But after all, why not just trim the strings right where you compare them, in the key event?

Comment: My question was answered regarding the trim and it's getting into questions about other things now. I'll check out the debugger thanks

Comment: I checked the debugger and it seems the trim occurs after the value I'm looking for it searched for. That's why it isn't working, looking at how to trim when the datagridview is populated with data instead.